# How can I use c language to interact with shell

Tags: c, shell, ssh

May I ask if there is any method to interact with shell using C language?
My main goal is to execute commands using SSH,
for example, ssh root@192.168.1.1 ls.
However, the target computer requires a password. I have tried using popen, openpty, and pipe, but none of them allow me to input the password.
It seems that I can handle general prompts such as whether to accept a connection with "y/n"
but I am unable to send the password.

Comment: have you succeeded in running ssh using a password from the terminal ?  get that working first before automating it via c

Comment: See: https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass

Comment: Is the problem running a shell child process, or is the problem about using the `ssh` command? These are completely separate tasks.

Comment: Verbal descriptions are often/usually ambiguous (as is yours). Readers need code to look at to understand the particular issues in your problem. Read about [mcve] and update your question with the smallest/easily-built code that demonstrates your problem. Include sample inputs and expected outputs (or behaviors). Use the `{}` tool from the *Edit* menu on mouse-selected text to achieve correct `code/data/output/errMsg` formatting. ....

Comment: Be sure to include 1) a small sample script(s) and arguments on the local network (127.1.1) (`echo "hello world"` ?) 2) required output or action from that script 3) current small code, 4) current behavior (output) of that code, 5) exact text of error messages. Also read  the section [How to turn a bad script into a good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) (this advice applies to all languages, not just bash)  Good luck.